# Adding data to a JavaScript object literal

Tags: javascript

This is my object literal:

```
var obj = {key1: value1};
```

How can I add

```
{key1: value1,value2,value3}
```

to `obj`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of your object would have to be an array or object that stores the separate values, like so:

```
{key1: [value1,value2,value3]}
```

Or

```
{key1: new compositeValue(value1, value2, value3)}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I have to wait another 13 minutes before I can accept